# Data used in WhatsApp

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-data-usage

If I am sending a text message of 100 letters/digits over WhatsApp then how can I measure the size of the text message in mb and what is its connection with the MB required for sending that message.
Similarly if I am sending an image of size x mb then how much of data will be used for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 3G watchdog [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog) . To monitoring data usages, after send message just back to 3G watchdog app and see how many data are used

Comment: there is check mark right below the down arrow in left of the answer